# How to make a python Package?

Tags: python, package, directory-structure

Here is my structure,

```
main.py
folder1\
    button.py
    folder2\
        picturebutton.py
folder3\
     listbox.py
     folder4\
         customlistbox.py
         folder5\
             hyperlistbox.py
```

Now,

I have a module called, "widget.py" and I would like to make it accessible to all the modules here so that each module will be able to say `import widget` or something of the sort. After googling, it appears that I have to make a package to do this.

I could not function with the examples online as I have no idea how they work, and I am hoping that one of you may be able to help me with my case.

Edit:
All the folders, (except for the root one) have an `__init__.py` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being able to import some other module does not need for that to be a package, it needs for the `widget` module to be put on your `PYTHONPATH`. You'd do that typically by installing it (writing a `setup.py` file, see the standard library's `distutils` module).

If you did want a package though, every folder that needs to be a package needs to have an `__init__.py` file in it (empty is fine).

Comment: If I were to put `widget.py` in the main root, I would not be able to access it from child directories.

Comment: You would if the directory it's in (your "root" directory here) is on your `PYTHONPATH`. Put `widget` in the root of that only if it's actually related to the rest of the stuff there.

Comment: Will this method still work if I freeze the application? Also, I forgot to mention, all my folders (except the root) have __init__.py files.

Comment: Well, the root directory needs one too. Freeze how? Are you talking about `cx_Freeze`?

Comment: Yes, cx_Freeze or py2exe. Is there a way to do this without putting the widget module in the `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: Then yes, `cx_Freeze` should take care of that fine. And no, the proper way to import Python modules is to have them on your `PYTHONPATH`. Is there something making that difficult?

Comment: I would just prefer not to put it in the PYTHONPATH, as it gives me an awkward feeling and making backups will take slightly longer but if this is the only way that it can be done, then so be it.

Answer (score 0):

Proper way is to create a setup.py file for your package but since it may take time . Below is shortcut .

If you want to use your module it frequently like in script . Easy way is to export "PYTHONPATH" in bashrc/zshrc file and give path to the directory containing your code .

For example:

```
   export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$HOME/path/to/package
```

Do check on terminal using

```
echo "$PYTHONPATH"
```

Happy Coding